# How to generate a list of all possible alphabetical combinations based on an input of numbers

Tags: python, algorithm, alphabetical

I have just come across an interesting interview style type of question which I couldn't get my head around.

Basically, given a number to alphabet mapping such that `[1:A, 2:B, 3:C ...]`, print out all possible combinations.

For instance "123" will generate `[ABC, LC, AW]` since it can be separated into 12,3 and 1,23.

I'm thinking it has to be some type of recursive function where it checks with windows of size 1 and 2 and appending to a previous result if it's a valid letter mapping.

If anyone can formulate some pseudo/python code that'd be much appreciated.

Comment: What about `1`, `2` and `3` alone?

Comment: Yeah, that's ABC, I didn't include that since I thought it was a given, but I'll edit it in.

Comment: No it's `A`, `B`, `C`

Comment: No, since it would need to consider the entire input. Unless you're talking about separate inputs of "1", "2", "3", and not "123"

Comment: Define separated() with a bit more vigour and please explain if 12 is 'L' what would be the complete answer for an input of "12". Would it include "U" ?

Comment: What can the lengths of the string be, can it be like: `"234"` (where `34` cannot be a valid alphabet??

Comment: 12 can either be "AB" or "L". Don't know where you got "U" from. Lengths of the string can be any amount, so for "234" you can get "BCD" or "WD" since 34 isn't anything, so a "D" would always be included in all the answers.

Comment: How are you going to map 0 with ..??

Comment: 0 is nothing, like 27 is nothing.

Comment: @user2027556, do you have a better task spec? You have not clearly stated how the number can be split - just given an example for which getting extracting a general rule is difficult.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. The number can be split any way that allows it to be mapped to an alphabetical letter, so anywhere between 1-26. Just look at my answer or any of the other posted answers to the problem.

Answer (score 1):

**As simple as a tree**

Let suppose you have give "1261"

Construct a tree with it a Root .

By defining the node(left , right ) , where left is always direct map and right is combo

version suppose for the if you take given Number as  1261

1261 ->

(1(261) ,12(61)) ->  **1 is left-node(direct map -> a) 12 is right node(combo-map1,2->L)**

(A(261) , L(61)) ->

(A(2(61),26(1))) ,L(6(1)) ->

(A(B(6(1)),Z(1)) ,L(F(1))) ->

(A(B(F(1)),Z(A)) ,L(F(A))) ->

(A(B(F(A)),Z(A)) ,L(F(A)))

so now you have got all the leaf node..

just print all paths from root to leaf node , this gives you all possible combinations .

like in this case

ABFA , AZA , LFA

So once you are done with the construction of tree just print all paths from root to node

which is your requirement .

Answer (score 1):

So I managed to hack together an answer, it's not as pythonic as I'd like and there may be some redundancies, but it works with the 123 example to output ABC,AW, and LC.

I'll probably clean it up tomorrow (or if someone wants to clean it up), just posting it in case someone is also working on it and is wondering.

```
def num_to_alphabet(numbers, ans = ""):
if not numbers:
    print ans
numbers = str(numbers)
window = numbers[:2]
alph = string.uppercase
ans = ans[:]
ans2 = ans[:]
window_val = ""
try:
    if window[0]:
        val = int(numbers[0])-1
        if alph[val]:
            ans += alph[val]
            num_to_alphabet(numbers[1:], ans)
    if window[1]:
        val = int(window) -1 
        if alph[val]:
            ans2 += alph[val]
            if len(window) > 1:
                num_to_alphabet(numbers[2:],ans2)
            else:
                num_to_alphabet(numbers[1:],ans2)
except IndexError:
    pass
```

Comment: Also there's some indention issues when trying to copy paste the code into stackoverflow

Answer (score 0):

```
charMap = {'1':'A', '2':'B' ... }
def getNodes(str):
    results = []
    if len(str) == 0: return results
    c = str[0]
    results.append(c)
    results = results.join(c.join(getNodes(str[1:])))
    if str[:2] in charMap.keys(): results = results.join(c.join(getNodes(str[2:])))
    return results
def mapout(nodes):
    cArray = []
    for x in nodes:
        cx = ''
        for y in x:
            cx = cx + charMap.get(y)
        cArray.append(cx)
    return cArray
res = getNodes('12345')
print(mapout(res))
```

Untested, but I believe this is along the lines of what you're looking for.

Comment: Doesn't work... Check the `results.join` part... By the way, this is Python Not C/C++ or VB, Follow [PEP-8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)

Comment: Yeah doesn't run, I don't think you'd have to join, wouldn't just += work? Thanks for the code though, I'll try to parse the logic and incorporate into my own solution.

Comment: Schoolboy, instead of simply referencing the standard please also state what is wrong with my convention. I am downloading python now to debug this.

Comment: @Montycarlo Um.. It's not Pythonic! :)

Comment: By being oversimplified? Sorry you couldn't interpret my code.

Comment: I said pseudocode/python is fine, so his answer's fine (although it could be better if it actually ran).

Comment: Well, all I wanted to say was *Most people who use Python **Follow** the convention set by PEP-8*. So, it would be better if you did so too. Let's not talk about the naming of the variables, but of debugging your code.. What do you intend to do with `result.join`??

Comment: Amusing that someone so concerned about readability conventions doesn't adhere to basic grammar. To append the argument array elements to the subject array.

I will address this question when I return home from work. There are  two logic errors with my code here that I've identified. This question is fun.

Comment: I wish people would stop proselytizing others about PEP8. It’s just a guideline. It’s okay, not to follow it explicitely. And a non-PEP8 answer is still better than no answer.

Comment: I agree, otherwise it should be enforced as syntax. OP has beat me to the punch and answered his own question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16186133/2058842

Answer (score 0):

The following answer recursively tries all possibilities at the current position (there are more than two!) and goes on with the remainder of the string. That's it.

```
from string import ascii_uppercase

def alpha_combinations(s):
    if len(s) == 0:
        yield ""
        return
    for size in range(1, len(s) + 1):
        v = int(s[:size])
        if v > 26:
            break
        if v > 0:
            c = ascii_uppercase[v - 1]
            for ac in alpha_combinations(s[size:]):
                yield c + ac 

print(list(alpha_combinations(input())))
```

It expects a number as a string. It gives correct output for `101010` (`['AAJ', 'AJJ', 'JAJ', 'JJJ']`). (I think some of the other solutions don't handle zeroes correctly.)

Answer (score 0):

So, I wanted to tackle this as well, since it’s actually a cool problem. So here goes my solution:

If we ignore the translations to strings for now, we are essentially looking for [partitions of a set](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_of_a_set). So for the input `123` we have a set `{1, 2, 3}` and are looking for partitions. But of those partitions, only those are interesting which maintain the original order of the input. So we are actually not talking about a set in the end (where order doesn’t matter).

Anyway, I called this “ordered partition”—I don’t know if there actually exists a term for it. And we can generate those ordered partitions easily using recursion:

```
def orderedPartitions(s):
    if len(s) == 0:
        yield []
        return
    for i in range(1, len(s)+1):
        for p in orderedPartitions(s[i:]):
            yield [s[:i]] + p
```

For a string input `'123'`, this gives us the following partions, which is exactly what we are looking for:

```
['1', '2', '3']
['1', '23']
['12', '3']
['123']
```

Now, to get back to the original problem which is asking for translations to strings, all we need to do is check each of those partitions, if they contain only valid numbers, i.e. 1 to 26. And if that is the case, translate those numbers and return the resulting string.

```
import string
def alphaCombinations(s):
    for partition in orderedPartitions(str(s)):
        # get the numbers
        p = list(map(int, partition))

        # skip invalid numbers
        if list(filter(lambda x: x < 1 or x > 26, p)):
            continue

        # yield translated string
        yield ''.join(map(lambda i: string.ascii_uppercase[i - 1], p))
```

And it works:

```
>>> list(alphaCombinations(123))
['ABC', 'AW', 'LC']
>>> list(alphaCombinations(1234))
['ABCD', 'AWD', 'LCD']
>>> list(alphaCombinations(4567))
['DEFG']
```

Comment: Nice, this is a very interesting and pythonic way to tackle the problem!

Answer (score 0):

I still am not sure of the description, but this Python script first partitions the num into its 'breaks' then tries each break member as a whole as an index into its corresponding character; then converts each digit of the member into letters of a word. Both contributions are shown before showing the sum total of all conversions to letters/words for the num "123"

```
>>> import string
>>> mapping ={str(n):ch for n,ch in zip(range(1,27), string.ascii_uppercase)}
>>> num = '123'
>>> [[num[:i], num[i:]] for i in range(len(num)+1)]
[['', '123'], ['1', '23'], ['12', '3'], ['123', '']]
>>> breaks = set(part for part in sum(([num[:i], num[i:]] for i in range(len(num)+1)), []) if part)
>>> breaks
{'123', '12', '3', '1', '23'}
>>> as_a_whole = [mapping[p] for p in breaks if p in mapping]
>>> as_a_whole
['L', 'C', 'A', 'W']
>>> by_char = [''.join(mapping[n] for n in p) for p in breaks]
>>> by_char
['ABC', 'AB', 'C', 'A', 'BC']
>>> everything = sorted(set(as_a_whole + by_char))
>>> everything
['A', 'AB', 'ABC', 'BC', 'C', 'L', 'W']
>>>
```